# Finding limits of two functions of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, problem-solving

Show using the definition of limit that
$$\lim _{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} = -1$$
and
$$\lim_{ (x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{ (1-\cos(xy))\sin y}{(x^2+y^2) }= 0$$

> **Definition of limit:**
>
> $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y) =L$ if and only if for every $\epsilon >0$ exist $\delta>0$ such that if $((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^{1/2}<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE, here you can ask for hints for your solution, you can try tell us what you have tried or your attempts to solve your question.

Answer (score 1):

We give more or less full detail for the first problem, and treat the second problem more casually.  Let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given. Note that
$$\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-(-1)\right|=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}.\tag{1}$$

Suppose that $\delta\le \frac{1}{2}$. We will need to put additional conditions on $\delta$ later.

If $\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-1)^2}\lt \delta$, then $(y-1)^2\lt \frac{1}{4}$ and therefore $|y-1|\lt \frac{1}{2}$. It follows that $y\gt \frac{1}{2}$. Thus $y^2\gt \frac{1}{4}$, and therefore $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}\lt 4$. It follows that $\frac{2x^2}{x^2+y^2}\lt 8x^2$.

We want to make sure that $8x^2\lt \epsilon$.  Note that $\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}\gt |x|$. So if $\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}\lt \frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}{\sqrt{8}}$, then $x^2\lt \frac{\epsilon}{8}$, and therefore $8x^2\lt \epsilon$.

So if we set $\delta=\min(1/2,\sqrt{\epsilon}/\sqrt{8})$, then if $\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}\lt \delta$ then the expression on the left side of (1) will be less than $\epsilon$.

For the second problem, we just mention the basic strategy. We are interested in the absolute value of $\frac{(1-\cos(xy))\sin y}{x^2+y^2}$. Multiply top and bottm by $1+\cos(xy)$, and use the fact that $|\sin t|\le t$. We get that
$$\left|\frac{(1-\cos(xy))\sin y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{(x^2y^2)|y|}{(|1+\cos(xy)|)(x^2+y^2)}.$$

Now if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is small enough (and it doesn't have to be very small!) we have $1+\cos(xy)\gt 1$. Also, since $(x-y)^2\ge 0$, we have $\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{1}{2}$ unless $(x,y)=(0,0)$.  The $\epsilon$ stuff should now be straightforward. There is a lot of slack. Even if $1-\cos(xy)$ is replaced by its square root, the limit is $0$.